# Specify the child's type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm creating a rather complex nested form. I have different "widgets" that I need to fill in data for. And the "composite widget", that in turn can contain multiple widgets. In other words my form is either for one widget, or for one widget that contains multiple.

And the following is the typing I've got currently:

```
type Kpi = {kpi: string};
type Svg = {svg: string};

type Composite = {widgets: Widget[]}

type Widgets = Kpi | Svg | Composite;
type Form<T extends Widgets> = {name: string; widget: T}
```

In the Svg form component I need to register fields for the react-hook-form to kick in and validate the form. In order to do so I need to provide the whole type of the form

```
const Svg = () => {
    const { register, formState } = useFormContext<Form<Svg>>;
}
```

It works perfectly until I need to use this component inside of a composite widget. I want to show the SVG component, that the form consists of composite widget, and it has one SVG widget inside. Something like this:

```
const Svg = () => {
    const { register, formState } = useFormContext<Form<Svg> | Form<Composite<Svg>>>;
}
```

I'm still unsure how to rewrite Composite type. I tried this:

```
type Composite<T extends Widgets = Widget> = {widgets: (Widget | T)[]}
```

But I react-hook-form form context doesn't pick it up and ultimately I can access svg widget as a child of a composite.

What is the right way of creating this structure? How to specify what kind of a child in an array I'm expecting?